# Introduction to C++ assignment : parallel arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am a beginner student looking for help on a program my professor assigned. The task is to use 2 parallel loops to ask the user 5 different salsas and their cost. Then print out the name, total sold, average, best seller and worst selling. The thing is, I can calculate best and worst selling, but those are ints. I don't understand how I can pull the string instead of int? Any help would be appriciated!#include

```
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string name[5];
    int total[5];
    int i, final, counter, high, low;

    for(i=0; i<=4; i++){
        cout << "Salsa name: ";
        cin >> name[i];
        cout << "How many of " << name[i] << " were sold? ";
        cin >> total[i];
        final += total[i];

        if(i < 0) {
            "Sorry, you cannot have negative sales!";
            return 0;
        } else {
            if(counter == 0) {
                low = total[i];
            } else if (total[i] < low) {
                low = total[i];
            } else if (total[i] > high) {
                high = total[i];
            } counter++;
        }
    }

        cout << "Name          Amount Sold\n"
             << "-------------------------\n";
        for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
            cout << name[i] << "        " << total[i] << endl;
        }


    cout << "Total sold: " << final << endl
         << "Most Sold: " << high << endl
         << "Least Sold: " << low;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Running /home/ubuntu/workspace/Ch6_Ex3.cpp
Salsa name: salsa1
How many of salsa1 were sold? 10
Salsa name: salsa2
How many of salsa2 were sold? 20
Salsa name: salsa3
How many of salsa3 were sold? 30
Salsa name: salsa4
How many of salsa4 were sold? 40
Salsa name: salsa5
How many of salsa5 were sold? 50
Name          Amount Sold
-------------------------
salsa1        10
salsa2        20
salsa3        30
salsa4        40
salsa5        50
Total sold: 32862
Most Sold: 50
Least Sold: -547659664

Process exited with code: 0
```

Comment: The string will be at the same position as that int, but in the other array.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some hiccups:

- There is no point in the variable `counter` because you mean it to have the same value as `i`, so use `i`; nor do you initialize it. Comparing `counter == 0` is undefined behaviour.
- Instead of keeping track of the highest/lowest values in `total`, you should instead keep track of the indexes of those specific values, because the corresponding value in `names` is the name of each salsa brand...

#### Take note of the changes below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string name[5];
    int total[5];

    int i;
    int final = 0;

    int high, low;
    high = 0, low = 0;

    for(i=0; i<=4; i++){
        cout << "Salsa name: ";
        cin >> name[i];
        cout << "How many of " << name[i] << " were sold? ";
        cin >> total[i];
        final += total[i];

        // if(i < 0) {
        //     "Sorry, you cannot have negative sales!";
        //     return 0;
        // }
        // i is never going to be less than 0.

        if (total[high] < total[i])
            high = i;
        if (total[low] > total[i])
            low = i;
    }

    // ...

    cout << "Most-sold salsa: " << name[high]
         << "\nLeast-sold: " << name[low] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Other notes:

- I strongly advise against `using namespace std;` [See why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
- You initially forgot `#include <iostream>`

Comment: Ahh, I see! thank you for the help. I wasnt taught the name[high] thing, thank you for teaching this to me!